# Creating a Blog using Firebase and AJAX

Tags: ajax, blogs, firebase

I'm new to web design, and as part of some school work, I am required to create a blog, and use Firebase to store posts. I have created two pages, one for viewing the blog posts and one for creating a new post. However, I am unsure of how to 'link' the Firebase and my webpage. Could someone explain to me how get started with linking text boxes on a page to some form of data storage (such as Firebase) and then how to display these posts on a separate page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [official Firebase Docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web-quickstart.html). Basically, you first load the Firebase library from their [CDN](https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js), then you create a reference to your database, and you can finally [read data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html) from your database reference.

Here's an example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myRef = new Firebase('https://myprojectname.firebaseIO-demo.com/');
  myRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // do something here, using "snapshot.val()" to access the value from your database
  });
</script>
```

I'm not experienced with FireBase, but they do have pretty good docs, so you should be able to do what you're trying to do without to much difficulty.